# Проектирование и разработка приложений на Java

Tags: maven, ant, проект, проектирование, java

Доброго времени суток!

Не так давно появился интерес к тому как проектируются, разрабатываются и собираются корпоративные приложения на Java. Интересуют средние по ёмкости приложения.

Как обычно проектируются приложения? Например, какое-нибудь клиент-серверное ПО.

Использются ли CASE технологии или какие-то другие?

Какую роль здесь играют системы сборки типа Maven?

Какие системы управления проектами используются?

Какой стиль кода используется в вашей компании?

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show me the code.(c)
Torvalds, Linus.

Comment: > Какой стиль кода используется в вашей компании?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список ссылок для самостоятельного ознакомления:

- Сборка: [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)
- Билд-серверы, CI: [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) ([Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)), [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/overview)
- Контроль качества кода: [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)
- Хранилище артефактов: [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)
- Репозитории кода: [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/), [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview)
- Багтрекинг, планирование работ: [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview/), [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), [Project Kaizer](http://www.projectkaiser.com/ru/)
- Проектирование: [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/), [Poseidon for UML](http://www.gentleware.com/products.html), [Enterpise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/), [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что сначала делаются диаграммы UML, а только потом пишется код? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: uml - это утопия)))

Comment: А как все же тогда проектируется это всё перед тем как писать код? И для чего нужны билд-сервера?

Comment: Билд-серверы могут много чего. Например по коммиту в репозиторий собрать проект в чистой среде, прогнать тесты, отправить уведомление разработчику запоровшему сборку, отправить код на проверку качества в тот же Sonar, упаковать собранный проект и выложить, например, на FTP, или даже сразу развернуть на сервере. И все это наглядно, визуально, без необходимости описывать это все скриптами.

Comment: > Вы имеете ввиду что сначала делаются диаграммы UML

Я тут вообще ничего не имею в виду. Я подкинул ссылок )

UML (как и все остальное в списке) это инструмент, а не объект поклонения. Можно использовать его с пользой, а можно и во вред.

Comment: И что такое артефакты? :) Где об этом почитать можно?

Comment: Артефакты - это то, что вы получаете после сборки. Это могут быть разные вещи, в зависимости от того, с какой целью вы сборку запускаете и что именно она вам создает: jar-ы, war-ы, текстовые логи логи, sql-скрипты,  файлы данных какой-нибудь СУБД, готовые дистрибутивы (msi пакет, например). В общем, конечный продукт.

Answer (score 1):

В своей работе я использую систему сборки [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). Советую ознакомиться.